# Adsense Notice Modified ad behavior

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I have an Adsense account with an Android app which has a single ad in it and it opens a website(not mine) which has 1-2 ads. My adview is in linear layout and I have used width as match_parent (to use gravity to make it appear in center horizontally) and inflated in a view at the top over the webpage. I got a notice with stopped ad serving to my app. The notice says

**MODIFIED AD BEHAVIOR: As stated in our program policies, publishers are not permitted to alter the behavior of ads in any way. The number of ads on a single screen should not exceed one if the ad is fixed to the screen top or screen bottom. If the page scrolls, only one ad should be visible on screen at a time.**

Please can anyone tell me what it actually means and suggest me proper way to resolve the issue and get my ad serving back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app

1. Displays an AdView
2. Also shows a WebView of a web page that shows ads

Then you are violating Admob's terms of policy by showing more than one ad.

Comment: 1. Even if that ad displayed on webview is  not mine, I mean website is not mine so ads also ??                                     2. If at some particular time a user is surfing a website and that contain ads!? In that case browsers are always violating?                                              Please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether website is yours or not. If you choose to display website that *may* have ads inside your app alongside ads that you are displaying then my reading is that you would be in breach.